# How to go back from search panel to the last opened text editor in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's say I edit a file and then I want to do a search (ctrl+shift+f). Then, I decided to go back to the editor.
My question is: how to do that without a mouse?

There are options which don't work:
`esc` - no, does'n work, `ctrl+k+q` - this is for navigation to the last editing position, `ctrl+tab` - no, `alt+left/right` - no.

Perhaps, I'm missing something. Thank you in advance for you help!

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+1` for the editor in column 1, use 1..9,

`Ctrl+Shft+E` to get the explorer,

`Ctrl+0` gets you to the bar

Answer (score 0):

I [tab]bed over to the [x] on the far right of the search panel (took seven tab keystrokes for me), hit [enter], and there I was, back in the editor.

Comment: Thank you, but I think it would be easier to press ```ctrl+f``` and then ```esc```. However I'm looking for straightforward way to activate my editor, from where I came to search or explorer or whatever...